# Efficiently search large DB for similar records

Tags: database, algorithm

Suppose the following: as input, one would get a record consisting of N numbers and booleans. This vector has to be compared to a database of vectors, which include M additional "result" elements. That means, the database holds P N+M sized vectors.

Each vector in the database holds as last element a boolean. The aim of the exercise is to find as fast a possible the record(s) which are closest match to the input vector AND have a resulting vector ending with a TRUE boolean.

To make the above a bit more comprehensible, give the following exampe:

A database with personal health information, consisting of records holding:

- age
- gender
- weight
- lenght
- hearth issues (boolean)
- lung issues (boolean)
- residence
- alternative plan Chosen (if done)
- accepted offer

The program would then search get an input like
36 Male 185pound 68in FALSE FALSE NYC

It would then find out which plan would be the best to offer the client, based on what's in the database.

I know of a few methods which would help to do this, eg the levenshtein distance method. However, most methods would involve searching the entire database for the best matches.

Are there any algorithms, methods which would cut back on the processing power/time required? I can't imagine that eg. insurance agencies don't use more efficient methods to search their databases...

Any insights into this area would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I guess insurance agencies would create a model through data mining: a decision tree, random forest, neural network, etc. Do you really need to _search_ the database, or is it okay to get the best 'offer' given a vector? That's called [classification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification)

Comment: Thanks, neural networks is indeed a good possibility. However i fear about the applicability on large databases (>1M records). Wouldn't it become impractible?

Answer (score 0):

Assumption: this is a relational database. If instead it were NOSQL then please provide more info on which db.

Do you have option to create **bitmap indexes**?  They can cut down the # of records returned . That is useful for almost all of the columsn since the cardinalities are low.

After that the only one left is the residence, and you should use a Geo distance for that.

If you are unable to create bitmap indexes then what **are** your filtering options?  If none then you have to do a full table scan.

For each of the components e.g. age, gender, etc. you need to 
(a) determine a distance metric
(b) determine how to compute both the metric and the distance between different records.

I'm not sure an Levenshtein would work here - you need to take each field separately to find their contribution to the whole distance measure.

Comment: Thanks! It would indeed be a relational DB. Bitmap indexes seem to be a very interesting way to efficiently search such databases. Do i correctly understand that such bitmap indices are not suoported by MySQL? I am only familiar with these kind of databases...

Comment: apparently mysql does NOT support bitmap indexes. My background is heavier in oracle that provided since 8